# jQuery dialog not working Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on chrome extension. I have problem with opening jQuery dialog box.

I have this code

```
if (window.jQuery) {
    alert("YES");
    $("<div>My div content</div>").dialog();
    alert("YES2");
}
else {
    alert("NO");
}
```

first alert works but second one fails to open, so there some problem with

```
$("<div>My div content</div>").dialog();
```

any ideas what's wrong with it or how to fix

Comment: `dialog()` is not jQuery native method. It comes w/ jQueryUI. Are you sure you connected jQuery UI as well? https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: this is part from manifest where I load it. "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-ui.min.js", "jquery.min.js", "background.js"]
  } so yeah, it should be loaded as well

Comment: ui has to be loaded after jquery.

Comment: changed code. checked now and both jqueryis are loaded but box is still not shown

Comment: You can't show UI from the background page.

Comment: okay, than how can I inject this script into main page so it works?

Comment: @user2614823 `$('head').append('<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>');` also you will need probably to include also jquery UI CSS. It's on CDN too http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: You want to show a dialog over the current web page? Or open a new tab with a page of yours? Why don't you use a popup browser action?

Comment: I need dialog over current web page. Alert box is no go because I need modular one which is always on top.

Comment: You should run `jquery`, `jquery-ui`, and your code as content scripts. You can use `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, and you'll need to set up the proper permissions.

Comment: so I load background.js from content scripts and than use executeScript in background.js to show dialog? just .dialog() or do I have to inject it?

Comment: You will probably have to inject your scripts into the page content in order to show a dialog there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to append your `<div>` to DOM before make dialog from it:

```
$("<div>My div content</div>").appendTo( 'body' ).dialog();
```

Probably there something wrong w/ scripts connections. jquery should be included before jquery-ui

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5W8Uy/1/)

Comment: Works well for me http://jsfiddle.net/5W8Uy/1/ . Probably something w/ script connections.